# Android Context Weak Reference

Tags: android-asynctask, android-context, android, android-memory

In some of my apps I use a few singleton objects as "managers." I instantiate them in `Application.onCreate` and I pass them the `ApplicationContext`, which I store in a `WeakReference`.

Some of the "manager's" methods start a background task after being called from an `Activity`, so I pass the `Activity`'s `context` to the method, and keep a `WeakReference` to that as well (and use that inside of an `AsyncTask`). That reference is kept until the next time an `Activity` calls a method that goes to the background, when the `WeakReference` is set to the new `Activity`'s `context`.

My question is, does the `ApplicationContext` have to be kept in a `WeakReference`, and are there any problems with keeping the `Activity`'s `context` like that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason for keeping a `WeakReference` to the activity's context is so that you won't keep a reference to an `Activity` that has been or otherwise should be destroyed already. No such issue exists for the `Application`. A `WeakReference` is unnecessary in that case.

It's hard to comment on your use of the activity's context since you haven't detailed what you're using it for exactly. It sounds a little suspicious that you're swapping out the context for different activities. If you really need a specific activity's context, this might be ok, but if you simply want a valid `Context` to use with an `AsyncTask` then I'd consider rethinking your approach. It'll probably work, but it's a bit hacky. There are other options that may be more appropriate depending on your needs: [`IntentService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) and [`Loaders`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) are options to consider.

Comment: I'm under the impression that you must use an `Activity`'s `context` in an AsyncTask. Am I mistaken? Are there any situation where `ApplicationContext` can't be used? If there aren't, I'd much rather switch to using `ApplicationContext` (would make my life easier).

Comment: Just an addition to above, from what I know an `ApplicationContext` shouldn't be used when instantiating a `View`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 5):

In general, you do not have to keep the application context in a WeakReference. You should keep other kinds of Contexts in a WeakReference, though.