# How to pass Context to AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android

How to pass context in `Async Task` class which is coded in different java file from `Main Activity` but it called from main activity?

Below is my code:

```
 @Override

protected void onPostExecute(List<Movie_ModelClass> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (result != null) {
            Movie_Adapter movieAdapter = new Movie_Adapter(new MainActivity().getApplicationContext() , R.layout.custom_row, result);
            MainActivity ovj_main = new MainActivity();
            ovj_main.lv_main.setAdapter(movieAdapter);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(new MainActivity().getApplicationContext() ,"No Data Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

        }
        if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

Answer (score 90):

You could just pass a `Context` instance as a constructor parameter (and keep a `WeakReference` to it to avoid memory leaks).

For example:

```
public class ExampleAsyncTask extends AsyncTask {
    private WeakReference<Context> contextRef;

    public ExampleAsyncTask(Context context) {
        contextRef = new WeakReference<>(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
        Context context = contextRef.get();
        if (context != null) {
            // do whatever you'd like with context
        }
    }
}
```

And the execution:

```
new ExampleAsyncTask(aContextInstance).execute();
```

Comment: Because you have if (context != null) {, in what case would the context be null?

Comment: @David In case the `Context` gets destroyed during the execution of the `AsyncTask`. For example the `AsyncTask` holds a reference to an `Activity` and an orientation change occurs while `doInBackground` is executing.

Comment: but the context could also be destroyed without leaving the activity/orientation changes, only because the GC thinks so, it would happen rarely, but it could happen, and this would be good.

Comment: Thanks. I was a bit confused by what to do with the context, so I cast it to MainActivity (since that's what calls the task in my case): `MainActivity context = (MainActivity)contextRef.get();`. And of course it can be also used within 'doInBackground'.

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass the context in the constructor of your AsyncTask.

**MyAsyncTask.java**

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, List> {

    private final Context mContext;

    public MyAsyncTask(final Context context) {
         mContext = context;
    }
}
```

and then just use the mContext variable in your onPostExecute() method.

When you call your AsyncTask from your MainActivity, you pass the context to the constructor of MyAsyncTask.

**MainActivity.java**

```
final MyAsyncTask task = new MyAsyncTask(getApplicationContext());
task.execute();
```

Comment: The `AsyncTask` shouldn't retain a strong reference to the activity context.  There are many Q&As about this.  [Here's one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19531168/android-context-weak-reference).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same issue when trying to compress an image using an Async class. I had a constructor in place so I just added context as below

```
   public BackgroundImageResize(Context context, Bitmap bm) {
    if (bm != null){
        mBitmap = bm;
    }
    this.context =context;
}
```

Then i called the class like below,

public void uploadDevicePhoto(Uri imageUri){

```
BackgroundImageResize resize = new BackgroundImageResize(this,null);
resize.execute(imageUri);
```

}