# This field leaks a context object

Tags: android, kotlin

My code:

```
class HttpRequestTask(private val debtWsUrl : URI, debtorText : TextView) : 
      AsyncTask<Void, Void, Iterable<Debtor>?>() {
            val debtorText: TextView = debtorText
}
```

Why line with TextView shows warning:

> This field leaks a context object

?

How can I prevent this?

Comment: Take a look at this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37532046/6444297) which solved my problem.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You assign a View to your HttpRequestTask. Since a View requires a Context you are leaking it.

Just think what happen if the View has been destroyed but the Http Task is not finished yet.

That's why you should avoid assigning to Context relevant stuff inside methods which may give something back while the view has been already killed.

Remove the debtorText and return the value to set it inside your view.

Comment: How should I send the View or Context object without having this issue?

Answer (score 27):

Use a [WeakReference](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html).

```
val textRef: WeakReference<TextView> = WeakReference(debtorText)
```

Comment: Some year ago, I feel like WeakReference could be a silver bullet. But now I feel like I'm wrong. It would just bring you more trouble than convenience.

Comment: thanks! it worked for me using the context as object